# Javascript enters if statement when the condition should evaluate false

Tags: javascript, html

I have a problem where javascript enters the if statement when the condition should evaluate false. I have the javascript linked to a HTML. The HTML uses **form** as its input for each variable, when nothing is entered into any of the **form** input type, the javascript outputs "0".

When **5** is entered into ***initialVelocity***, and **45** is entered into ***finalVelocity*** the output is **50**.

Feel free to make fun of my coding style, all answers are appreciated!

```
function physicsFunction() {

var initialVelocity = document.getElementById('formInitialV').elements['initialVName'].value;
var finalVelocity = document.getElementById('formFinalV').elements['finalVName'].value;
var time = document.getElementById('formTime').elements['timeName'].value;
var acceleration = document.getElementById('formAcceleration').elements['accelerationName'].value;
var averageAcceleration = document.getElementById('formAvgAcceleration').elements['avgAccelerationName'].value;
var displacement = document.getElementById('formDisplacement').elements['displacementName'].value;
var averageVelocity = document.getElementById('formAvgVelocity').elements['avgVelocityName'].value;

if (initialVelocity !== undefined && acceleration !== undefined && time !== undefined) {
  var finalVelocity = (initialVelocity + acceleration * time);
  document.getElementById('paragraphOne').innerHTML = 'The final Velocity is about equal to: ' + finalVelocity +' m/s';
}}
```

Comment: Are you expecting `.value` on a text field to produce `undefined` when it is empty? Try alerting or console dot logging the values of `initialVelocity`, `acceleration`, and `time` just before the `if` statement.

Comment: `element.value` is never `undefined` for inputs

Comment: @JaromandaX what would the input return, just an empty string?

Comment: probably ... not sure about non type=text inputs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To obtain a real `undefined` value, you could use a function like:

```js
function UndefinedIfEmpty(value)
{
  if(value.trim() == "")
  {
     return undefined;
  }
  else
  {
    return value;
  }
}

// Use it:
// var initialVelocity = UndefinedIfEmpty(document.getElementById('formInitialV').elements['initialVName'].value);
// and so on

console.log("`` is ", UndefinedIfEmpty(""));
console.log("` ` is ", UndefinedIfEmpty(" "));
console.log("`12` is ", UndefinedIfEmpty("12"));
```

You should even convert into number, to avoid: `initialVelocity + acceleration * time` => `"12" + "4" * 13` => `"12" + 52 => "1252"` (string concatenation).

```js
function NumberOrUndefined(value)
{
  value = value.trim();
  if ( value == "" )
  {
    return undefined;
  }
  else
  {
    return parseInt(value, 10);
  }
}
// 10 in parseInt to avoid octal convertion

console.log("` ` is", NumberOrUndefined(" "));
console.log("12 is a ", typeof NumberOrUndefined("12"));
```